# Прокрутка в react-swipeable-views назад с первого элемента

Tags: reactjs

При использовании 'react-swipeable-views' пытаюсь реализовать скрол с первого элемента на последний

Грубо говоря, чтобы можно было крутить по кругу.

Компонент предлагает передать в параметрах Ось, но там только "x" | "x-reverse" | "y" | "y-reverse"

Мне бы хотелось узнать как решить данную задачу
перейти в один свайп - "назад с первого элемента"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена с помощью react-swipeable-views-utils:

```
import { virtualize } from "react-swipeable-views-utils";
import SwipeableViews, { SwipeableViewsProps } from 'react-swipeable-views';
const VirtualizeSwipeableViews = virtualize(SwipeableViews);

<VirtualizeSwipeableViews
  index={activeIndex}
  onChangeIndex={_onChangeIndex}
  slideRenderer={slideRenderer}
  enableMouseEvents
/>
```

он позволяет решить проблему бесконечного цикла без переключателя